# libGL / swrast error when running chromium-browser over X

Tags: rhel, x11, windows

I'm getting some errors when running `chromium-browser` over putty/xming tunnel.  I checked that libGL is already on the system (RHEL7).  What should I be checking first to address this issue?

Note, `xclock` runs fine, so the tunnel is working correctly.

```
$ chromium-browser
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[17484:17484:0530/203046.848309:ERROR:gl_surface_glx.cc(411)] GLX 1.3 or later is requir
ed.
[17484:17484:0530/203046.848349:ERROR:gl_initializer_x11.cc(136)] GLSurfaceGLX::Initiali
zeOneOff failed.
[17484:17484:0530/203046.850090:ERROR:child_thread_impl.cc(762)] Request for unknown Cha
nnel-associated interface: ui::mojom::GpuMain
[17484:17484:0530/203046.850174:ERROR:gpu_child_thread.cc(330)] Exiting GPU process due
to errors during initialization
[17442:17442:0530/203047.193418:FATAL:platform_font_linux.cc(63)] Check failed: typeface
. Could not find any font: Utopia, sans
#0 0x7f16fc8eeede base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#1 0x7f16fc90b0f7 logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
#2 0x7f16fa27f1f1 gfx::(anonymous namespace)::CreateSkTypeface()
#3 0x7f16fa27f650 gfx::PlatformFontLinux::PlatformFontLinux()
#4 0x7f16fa27f9a6 gfx::PlatformFont::CreateDefault()
#5 0x7f16fa26ff59 gfx::Font::Font()
#6 0x7f16fa272e46 gfx::FontList::GetDefaultImpl()
#7 0x7f16fa272f59 gfx::FontList::FontList()
#8 0x7f16fa29ba02 gfx::RenderText::RenderText()
#9 0x7f16fa291aa9 gfx::RenderTextHarfBuzz::RenderTextHarfBuzz()
#10 0x7f16fa299696 gfx::RenderText::CreateInstance()
#11 0x7f16f2c688b7 views::corewm::TooltipAura::TooltipAura()
#12 0x7f16f2c7ba3e views::DesktopWindowTreeHostX11::CreateTooltip()
#13 0x7f16f2c718d2 views::DesktopNativeWidgetAura::InitNativeWidget()
#14 0x7f16fe8a439b DesktopBrowserFrameAura::InitNativeWidget()
#15 0x7f16f2c5bde2 views::Widget::Init()
#16 0x7f16fe82d2ae BrowserFrame::InitBrowserFrame()
#17 0x7f16fe6eed0e BrowserWindow::CreateBrowserWindow()
#18 0x7f16fe650158 Browser::Browser()
#19 0x7f16fe66e8df StartupBrowserCreatorImpl::OpenTabsInBrowser()
#20 0x7f16fe66fc04 StartupBrowserCreatorImpl::RestoreOrCreateBrowser()
#21 0x7f16fe6720fa StartupBrowserCreatorImpl::ProcessLaunchUrlsUsingConsolidatedFlow()
#22 0x7f16fe67244b StartupBrowserCreatorImpl::Launch()
#23 0x7f16fe66d104 StartupBrowserCreator::LaunchBrowser()
#24 0x7f16fe66dedc StartupBrowserCreator::ProcessCmdLineImpl()
#25 0x7f16fe66e241 StartupBrowserCreator::Start()
#26 0x7f16fdc3c0cd ChromeBrowserMainParts::PreMainMessageLoopRunImpl()
#27 0x7f16fdc3c9d4 ChromeBrowserMainParts::PreMainMessageLoopRun()
#28 0x7f16f6f4e8dc content::BrowserMainLoop::PreMainMessageLoopRun()
#29 0x7f16f726e9d9 content::StartupTaskRunner::RunAllTasksNow()
#30 0x7f16f6f4f326 content::BrowserMainLoop::CreateStartupTasks()
#31 0x7f16f6f55d39 content::BrowserMainRunnerImpl::Initialize()
#32 0x7f16f6f4db42 content::BrowserMain()
#33 0x7f16f758e4ad content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::Run()
#34 0x7f16f758da29 content::ContentMain()
#35 0x7f16fd619624 ChromeMain
#36 0x7f16e7140b35 __libc_start_main
#37 0x7f16fd6194c4 <unknown>

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the error messages,

> GLX 1.3 or later is required

but Xming only supported version 1.2 when this question was asked. Current versions support newer versions of GLX (1.4).

Comment: interesting, thanks for the clarification, i hadnt noticed that as clear as you made it.  Im not sure what GLX is, but ill check into it, thanks.